# How can I create an instance from a UObject class?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I have a DataTable with a list of items that can be dropped by enemies, along with their rarities and min/max quantities:

```cpp
USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct FItemDropRow : public FTableRowBase
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly)
    TSubclassOf<UBattleItemBase> DropItemClass;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly)
    EItemRarity RarityTier;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly)
    int MinDrop;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly)
    int MaxDrop;
};
```

And here's the function on the character where the drops are selected:

```cpp
// Pick a random entry from a list of items filtered by rarity
int SelectedIndex = FMath::RandRange(0, UsableRowIndexArray.Num() - 1);

// Retrieve that entry from the DataTable
FItemDropRow* SelectedRow = ItemDropDataTable->FindRow<FItemDropRow>(
    UsableRowIndexArray[SelectedIndex],
    ContextString
);

// Pick a random amount to drop from the min/max defined on the DataTable row
int DropQuantity = FMath::RandRange(
    SelectedRow->MinDrop,
    SelectedRow->MaxDrop
);

// Initialize the array with the item instance and the quantity to add
TArray<UBattleItemBase*> ItemsToReturn;
ItemsToReturn.Init(SelectedRow->DropItemClass, DropQuantity);
return ItemsToReturn;
```

The issue is that the DataTable is only storing references to the classes:

```
C2664   'void TArray::Init(UBattleItemBase *const &,int)':
    cannot convert argument 1 from 'TSubclassOf' to 'UBattleItemBase *const &'
```

But I need it as an instance so I can add it to the player's inventory and modify it's quantity. I've tried the `Instanced` flag in the `FItemDropRow` struct, but that causes the DropItemClass to no longer appear as an editable property in the DataTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DropItemClass` is only the class of the item, not an instance of it.

If you want to create an instance from that class you can use [`NewObject()`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/ProgrammingWithCPP/UnrealArchitecture/Objects/Creation/) or one of the more advanced versions (`NewNamedObject()` / `ConstructObject()`, `CreateObject()`, etc...)

e.g.:

```cpp
TArray<UBattleItemBase*> ItemsToReturn;
for(int i = 0; i < DropQuantity; i++)
    ItemsToReturn.Add(NewObject<UBattleItemBase>(
        (UObject*)GetTransientPackage(),
        SelectedRow->DropItemClass
    ));
```

this would create `DropQuantity` instances of the specified `DropItemClass`.

The first parameter to `NewObject()` will be the `outer` for the newly created object, so if you want it to be owned by any object you should pass that one instead.